# Salesforce Apex Testing Code Coverage Issues for Simple Webhook

Tags: testing, salesforce, apex

I am very new at Salesforce and am stuck on writing testing for some webhooks - one as a button and one triggered upon opportunity creation.

Goal: Pass Test for Webhook (I have tested it manually in the sandbox many times and both webhooks work).

Question: Is there a very simple test or two that will show that the webhook work so I can pass this?

**Apex Trigger 1:** (button push triggering)

```
trigger WebhookTrigger on CustomObject (after insert) {
  String url = 'https://webhook.sample.com';
  String content = Webhook.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
  Webhook.callout(url, content);
}
```

**Apex Trigger 2**: (opportunity created triggering)

```
trigger opportunityCreatedTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {
  String url = 'https://webhook.sample1.com';
  String content = Webhook.jsonContent(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
  Webhook.callout(url, content);
}
```

**Apex Class: Webhook:**

```
public class Webhook implements HttpCalloutMock {
  public static HttpRequest request;
  public static HttpResponse response;
  public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    request = req;
    response = new HttpResponse();
    response.setStatusCode(200);
    return response;
  }
  public static String jsonContent(List<Object> triggerNew, List<Object> triggerOld) {
    String newObjects = '[]';
    if (triggerNew != null) {
        newObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerNew);
    }
    String oldObjects = '[]';
    if (triggerOld != null) {
        oldObjects = JSON.serialize(triggerOld);
    }
    String userId = JSON.serialize(UserInfo.getUserId());
    String content = '{"new": ' + newObjects + ', "old": ' + oldObjects + ', "userId": ' + userId + '}';
    return content;
  }

  @future(callout=true)
  public static void callout(String url, String content) {
    if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new Webhook());
    }
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setBody(content);
    h.send(req);
}
```

}

Comment: See [How do I write an Apex unit test?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244788/how-do-i-write-an-apex-unit-test), [How do I unit test code that includes a callout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244797/how-do-i-unit-test-code-that-includes-a-callout) on Salesforce Stack Exchange.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. In addition to review the resources provided in the previous comment, it would be helpful to know what test class you tried to create.  Looks like you code already has the callout mock included -- which is often where people get hung up. Have you tried to write the actual test class yet and what does that look like?